# take the value out of the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
erp.directive("auto1", [ '$http', function( $http) {
    var mydata;
    var x;
    var y;
    data = function(){
          return $http.get("./php/fetchElement.php").then(function (response) {
            mydata = this;
            mydata = response.data.records;             
        });
    };      
    function run(){
        return data().then(function(response){          
            return mydata.map(function(ele){
                return ele.Name;
            }); 

        }); 

    }
    x = run();
    console.log(x);

   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function() {      
        $('#auto1').autocomplete({source:[x]})     
   }
};
}]);
```

Please help me! I cannot take the array "ele.Name" out of the function. When inside it is an expected array. But when assign to "x" it is a complicated object that I cannot access for desired value.

Comment: `data.then()` returns a promise, not the result of the `then()` function. You will need to actually put your log statement inside of the then or you need to change the pattern so the caller is notified of the result of the then.

Comment: Use the remote data options of `autocomplete` plugin as outlined in documentation

Comment: Is there a way to access <code> ele.Name </code> outside the <code> then()  </code> that I can use it globally?